# how to use Naira Currency symbol for money format html

Tags: css, html, ionic-framework

I am trying to get the value of Total redemption to be on the same line with the word "Total Redemption" like the way Total Accrued Points looks, I am using an image for my currency symbol and the code for this display is

```
<div class="item item-body " >  
<div class="container">
 <div class="right">
 Total Accrued Points :  {{reportData.accruedpoints}}<br/>
 <p>Total Redemption:<img src='img/naira.gif' alt="Naira" height='20' width='20' align='bottom'> {{reportData.redeemableamt | currency : ""}}
</p>
</div>
<a  <a href="#/app/transactionsBreakDown/{{reportData.submerchantId}}" class="button button-full button-assertive ink" >View {{reportData.submerchantId}} Details</a>
```

[image]

Comment: Remove `align="bottom"`? Otherwise, check is styled to block.

Comment: i removed that still no effect

Answer (score 3):

Always use Unicode for text and currency

```html
&#8358; 12,000
```

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20a6/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

add `display: inline` to the CSS of your your image tag to display it inline within the paragraph:

```
<img src='img/naira.gif' alt="Naira" height='20'
width='20' align='bottom' style="display:inline;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `span` element

```html
<span><span>&#8358;</span> 15,000</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

just do this and you are good to go

```
{{basketTotal | currency: '&#8358; '}}
```

Comment: Code only answers are not very helpful.Please add an explanation how this solves the question